# jQuery load() function won't load remote page, but works in preview mode in text editor.

Tags: ajax, jquery

Basically, I am trying to fetch remote content when people click the link.

It works in Coda HTML preview window, but when I test the html in real browser (Chrome / FF / Safari), it won't work, the remote content won't be fetched. ( I am sure jquery is working, as alert('url is ' + url);  pops up when I click link)

It is wired. What is wrong?

[image]

[image]

My code as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sample</title>

  <link type="text/css" href="http://localhost/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#links a').click(function(e) {
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
                    alert('url is ' + url);  
            $('#content').load(url);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });  // document ready
  </script>

</head>

<body>

<ul id="links">
  <li><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a></li>

</ul>
<div id="content"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). It is a security feature of most browsers. The most common workaround is to use JSONP, but as you are expecting HTML as a response, this will not work for you.

What you will need to use is a server-side proxy, whereby you make your request in PHP/ASP.Net/other server side tech to get the HTML of the URL, then expose this to your jQuery via a local request.